# how to find absolute value for complex fraction

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, absolute-value

I have a Fourier transfer equation $H(jw) = \frac{jwL}{(jw)^2LC+jw\frac{L}{R}+1}$, and I need to find frequency to make $|H(jw)|$ is max. 
I know I should take the derivative of $|H(jw)|$ then find the max $w_0$. But my question now is how to find the absolute value of this function. \
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume that all the constants are $\gt 0$.  The denominator of your fraction is

$$1-\omega^2 L C + j \omega \frac{L}{R}$$

so the magnitude of the fraction is

$$\frac{\omega L}{\sqrt{(1-\omega^2 L C)^2 + \omega^2 L^2/R^2}}$$

Comment: @nealsmith: glad you did.  If this solution was helpful, please also remember to accept the solution by clicking the checkmark below the upvote counter.  Thanks.

Comment: @nealsmith Also note that to find the frequency to make the transfer function maximum it may be easier to take the log of the magnitude equation before differentiating, the frequency will be the same in either case.

Comment: Could anyone explain how he found the answer... I am bit confused here..